# lag/lead for previour year,same month,date,hour in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have year, month, day of month, hour column also sale column . The data is for four years. How to create lag varaibles for sales in next year, same month, day of month, hour?

```
SELECT 
   [UtilityName],
   [CustomerID],
   [DT_EST],
   [Date_Raw],
   [Hour_Raw],
   [EPT_Year],
   [EPT_month],
   [EPT_DayNum],
   [EPT_Hour24],
   [Sales], 
   lag([Sales]) over( partition by [UtilityName] ,[CustomerID],[EPT_month],
   [EPT_DayNum],[EPT_Hour24]  order by [DT_EST] ) as lag_Sales
FROM [dbo].[table]
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain why you are using unsupported software.

Comment: UtilityName CustomerID DT_EST Date_Raw Hour_Raw EPT_Year EPT_month EPT_DayNum EPT_Hour24 sales
Utility_04 CustID_2 00:00.0 4/2/2019 21:00:00:000 2019 4 3 22 2.340295095
Utility_04 CustID_2 00:00.0 4/10/2019 21:00:00:000 2019 4 4 22 3.480295095
@GordonLinoff

Comment: @prabhuprasad you should [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59774061/edit) your question with the relevant details. And you should provide sample data AND the desired output. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Not sure why you have this tagged with sql server 2008 and have LAG in your code. That function wasn't in sql server until sql server 2012.

Comment: Add month, hour, and day to partition by.

Comment: @scottsaenz i tried that also the date start from 2017-06-01 to 2019-08-31 . so all i need is in new lag column is till 2018-06-01 i need null and next row should hold the value for 2017-06-01 sales in that lag_column and succesively

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead using `left join`:

```
SELECT t.*, tprev.Sales as prev_year_sales
FROM [dbo].[table] t LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[table] tprev
     ON tprev.UtilityName = t.UtilityName AND
        tprev.CustomerId = t.CustomerId AND
        tprev.EPT_Year = t.EPT_Year - 1 AND
        tprev.EPT_month = t.EPT_month AND
        tprev.EPT_DayNum = t.EPT_DayNum AND
        tprev.EPT_Hour24 = t.EPT_Hour24;
```

Comment: i thought of this but i want to run this along with other select statement in a 600 gb table . so can i acheive with lag function    ? @Gordon

Comment: @prabhuprasad . . . You might find that `join` is more efficient, assuming the table is properly indexed.  Not 100% sure, but quite possibly.

Answer (score 0):

You must partition by month, day and hour also and order by year descending to get the previous year's value:

```
lag([Sales]) 
  over(partition by 
          [UtilityName] ,[CustomerID],
          [EPT_month], [EPT_DayNum], [EPT_Hour24]
       order by [EPT_Year] 
  ) as lag_Sales
```